# QGIS 3.10 open data source manager: How to load XYZ tiles

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, zxy

I have a thunderforest background map for my project for which I had not given an API key.  I now want to publish some maps and need to add the key to remove the overlay.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to change the urls for the layers.  I think I loaded it originally from the data manager => XYZ Tile menus (this matches what I found searching) but in the current version of QGIS that option is not listed.

I assume I could hack the project file and add the key to the url there but I would rather do this properly!

Comment: https://tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxx

Comment: I know the format of the url, what i can’t figure out is how to specify the new url.  The data source manager used to have an XYZTile option but it isn’t there in 3.10

Comment: 3.10 XYZ Tiles are in the browser now. https://mariosmsk.com/2019/07/01/how-to-add-xyz-tiles-with-two-ways-qgis/